# Auto Populate OTP in Azure AD B2C

Tags: javascript, sms, azure-ad-b2c, one-time-password

We have integrated Azure AD B2C with a native mobile application. All is working good except that the customer wants the OTP to be auto populated into the textbox(the way it happens in Swiggy/Airtel).
Is it possible? We tried inserting a JavaScript to read the SMS and populate the OTP but it simply doesn’t work.
Any pointers on how to get it working would certainly help.

Comment: Since you are using Xamarin, check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/verify-otp-automatically-in-android-without-sms-read-permission-using-xamarin-fo/) if helps.

Comment: Hi, the control is with Azure AD B2C and not Xamarin so the code wouldn't be able to help much.

Comment: ok..so is the B2C login screen loading within a Xamarin WebView or browser?

Comment: Xamarin embedded web view

Comment: Technically it seems there is not possible way to read SMS and auto populate.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT will it work in Xamarin browser view?